# how to parse more than 20k numbers json data

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, jquery-mobile

I do have api which consists more than 20k data, as of now am able to parse data through ajax script and set the value in list view, but its taking more time and responding slowly .
How can I improve the response ..
Please help.

```
  $.ajax({

    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: ({User: userName,Pass: userPass}),
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
         $('#work-in-progress').fadeOut(0);
        ajax.parseJSON(result);


    },
    error: function (request,error) {
        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');

        document.getElementById("internet_access").innerHTML="No internet access";
    }
});
```

Comment: by sending less text that JSON has to parse. Why is your JSON that big? Do you need all that data at once? Can you split the data into smaller chunks?

Comment: JSON.parse() will parse 20,000 numbers easily, not sure why you have a problem. Please post your code

Comment: 20,000 numbers in a mobile list view seems excessive, can you paginate this perhaps?

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: ({User: userName,Pass: userPass}),
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            
            ajax.parseJSON(result);
             
           
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
            
            document.getElementById("internet_access").innerHTML="No internet access";
        }
    });

Comment: I am calling that api in search box ..

Comment: let me take a wild guess, you've removed the part about how you render the result of `ajax.parseJSON(result)` in you success-handler, right? Could it be, that this code contains a loop and `.innerHTML += ...`?